# Almacenar en una variable de VBA la respuesta de una consulta de Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Tengo un formulario en Access que me muestra lo siguiente:
[image: Front del formulario]

Cuando hago clic en el botón "Destino" se abre la consulta:
[image: Captura de la consulta]

Dicha consulta **lo que hace es** **mostrarme el código de la caja que hemos puesto en el campo situado justo arriba del botón "Destino"**.

De modo que mi problema es el siguiente:
Necesito saber si hay alguna forma de **sacar ese código y almacenarlo en una variable VBA** para, posteriormente, introducirlo en el campo que hay situado a la derecha llamado "Código caja".

Esto lo que me permitiría posteriormente es cogerlo de ese campo ("Código Caja") y con los botones azules sustituir el que ya tiene el producto por el nuevo que es el situado en dicho campo.

Muchas Gracias de antemano

Comment: Si puedes hacerme llegar la aplicación...No entiendo bien qué quieres conseguir

Comment: Hay un objeto en VBA Access que precisamente hace referencia a las consultas. Úsalo, o bien crea una consulta igual desde VBA.